# I've lost my online site for Mead Making!

Tags: process, racking

I am making my fist batch of Honey Mead. I had followed the "fast mead making" recipe on " Stormthecastle", added the orange and the raisons, the balloon with pinhole first inflated and has now been deflated 2 days. The honey has disappeared and sediment is on the bottom. Total time elapsed has been approximately 6 weeks. ( I made the rookie error of not marking the start date but I know the approximate weekend)

I am now lost! I can't find any next steps and this is my first day on your site... My first post-
Please help!

Comment: Maybe first wait a day or two to see if their website gets up again?

Comment: I would also suggest that for the time being you make sure that your fermentation vessel is properly sealed with a cork.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, there is Archive.org to help you.  It took a snapshot of the webpage, it can be found here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210512151955/http://www.stormthecastle.com/mead/fast-cheap-mead-making.htm

Always save your recipes before starting ;-)

Cheers!